# Remove code in question when problem has been reduced to smaller part of the code

Tags: discussion, edits

A few days ago I asked a question here on Stack Overflow, in the question I included parts of code that might have to do with the problem (I didn't really have a clue what caused it). Half a day later I found more info about the problem and could reduce the problem to a smaller piece of code.

Should I then remove the earlier given code that became obsolete?

Comment: [Yes](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), remove everything that isn't essential to reproducing the problem.

Comment: Note that you don't want to make this type of edit on someone else's question. Suggesting an edit that removes someone else's code from their question is likely to get rejected.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it is expected that you keep looking for solution and update question with information found, including (but not limited to) edit code to show real [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

There is a good chance that you'll be *encouraged* to do so by downvotes on the question - editing question with solid MCVE will put it in front of more users as "active" and presumably your edit will be good to bring up-votes.

If the question already has valid answers (question was not too broad/unclear and answers actually answer the question) then you need to make sure to not invalidate the answers with your change. In case original code is used in answers you may want to keep original code at the bottom of the question and provide true MCVE in main part. In some cases asking new question may be more appropriate (if answers were about some other valid problem in the code so you can't actually provide MCVE that you are interested in without breaking answers).

Comment: "If the question already have valid answers (question was not too broad/unclear and answers actually answer the question) than you need to make sure to not invalidate the answers with your change." this is pure rubbish. If they couldn't wait for the OP to provide a valid MCVE is their fault, not the asker, for answering instead of waiting (or close voting, really). We already invalidate answers if the question needs to be edited to be reopened.

Comment: @Braiam I'm not sure why you claim it is ok to change reasonable question with answers into completely different one just because OP found another problem which they have MCVE for. Questions must have enough code to demonstrate problem (which seem to be the case here), true MCVE is desired but it should not completely change question especially when answers present. (Possibly I misunderstood your comment... or more likely did not cover something in the post).

Comment: I'm not sure why you claim that answers that focused on tangential issues should be kept on a question about a different matter altogether. Who cares if the original code had a minor side issue, and answerers picked the low hanging fruit to answer instead of going directly to the crux of the question. Why should answers prevent a question from being improved?

Comment: @PM2Ring "but if they completely remove the old code it can be a little confusing" how exactly? The new code reproduce the same result as the old one. Why would be that confusing? Both produce the same result.

Comment: @PM2Ring why would they? If the parsing is irrelevant, why should someone refer to it in their answer?

Comment: @PM2Ring I don't know you, but I write generic answers that works independently of the sample input. It's called *sample input* because it's a sample, it may be a simplified sample data not the real world, so if your solution isn't flexible enough to allow changes in the input, it is not useful and should be downvoted.

Comment: @PM2Ring then, why would it matter if the OP made the issue clearer by removing the parsing part of his solution? It's not related to the issue he's trying to solve, so obviously, if the answerers are figured that out, they wouldn't make reference to it.

Comment: @PM2Ring again, why "early answers have the parsing code" when it was never part of the problem?

Comment: @Braiam There are cases where a user asks a question which has a clear answer, then later realises that's not the actual issue they're having, and thus may be tempted to change the question and MCVE to something entirely different, which invalidates answers which were previously valid.  In this case, it is by no means the answerers' fault that the OP asked about the wrong problem, when the problem they did ask about had a clear, valid solution.

Comment: @JustinTime we are talking about **the same MCVE**! My code produce C instead of B when I foo the bar is exactly the same however you foo the bar.

Comment: @Braiam I'm talking in general, not about any specific examples.  There are cases where the OP might know about multiple problems in their code, but not know which is causing a specific issue they're having trouble with; in this type of situation, it's plausible that they might realise they asked about and posted an MCVE for the wrong problem, and change them to be about one of the other problems instead.

Comment: @Braiam If you say that your **all** answer are generic to handle **all** the scenarios than I doubt your words. Solution is very much dependent on the kind of data one is dealing with. Many a times genericness impacts the performance of solution. It is responsibility of the OP to post MCVE that includes the sample data sets.

Comment: @Braiam As far as answer solves the question, it is a valid answer. And if later the OP changes the question which makes the posted answer invalid, that is incorrect. Because that change makes the answer, the efforts, the time of the answerer go in vain. Probably he'll get down votes for his efforts (because context of question is changed now). Ultimately answerer will receive criticism from the community for helping OP (which is really really BAD for the SO contributors). Remember, contributors are not paid to help others, they do it voluntarily. It is our job to prevent them from criticism.

Answer (score 1):

Try to always post a MCVE at the first moment. Remember that you have plenty of time before asking your question to include just the necessary to reproduce the problem.

Though, if a MCVE wasn't possible, or another way to reproduce the problem easily is found, don't be shy of editing. Editing is explicitly encouraged, specially if it improves the post, and nothing improves the chances of a question being correctly answered than including all the necessary context to provide the best possible answer.